# Cannot SSH with hostname on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, hostname

I'm trying to configure my Raspberry Pi using Ansible and the first thing that I did was to change the hostname in the /etc/hosts file via Ansible and I was able to do that. After running my Ansible playbook, I can see the following in my remote Raspberry Pi's /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.1.1 m1.open-electrons.com pi
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Now from my local machine, I try to ssh using this hostname like:

```
$ ssh pi@m1.open-electrons.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname m1.open-electrons.com: Name or service not known
```

But when I do:

```
$ ssh pi@m1.local
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1012-raspi aarch64)
.......
.......
```

Why is this? What am I doing wrong? Kind of blocked with this since hours.

Comment: The hosts file is used by the machine itself to look up hostnames. It's got nothing to do with how other systems look up the machine's name. For that you need DNS

Comment: So that means I do not have a DNS server running on my local machine. Correct? But how is it able to resolve m1.local and successfully ssh into?

Comment: I added a config to the .ssh folder and it did the trick!

Comment: That allows one machine (the one on which you changed the ssh config) to reach your Pi with a custom name

Comment: I only need to access the pi from my local machine. So it is fine for now. I might add it to a DNS server if I'm out of my home network, but that will never be the case!

Comment: Then the local machine is the only place you need to put your invented name for the Pi